# In a normed space, is it always true that $\|a_1e_1+\dots+a_ne_n\|\geq |a_i|\|e_i\|$?

Tags: normed-spaces

In a normed space, is it true in general that $\|a_1e_1+\dots+a_ne_n\|\geq |a_i|\|e_i\|$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$?

$e_i$ are basis elements of the vector.

This is definitely true for the Euclidean metric, and $\|.\|_p$ for all $p\in\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Thanks in advance! I'm trying to prove Riesz's lemma and this would make things very easy.

Comment: what are the $e_i$s?

Comment: The basis elements.

Comment: also what is the lemma you are trying to prove?

Comment: I'm trying to prove [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you state is **not** true. Here is a simple counter example:

Take for example $a_2 = -a_1$ and $e_2=e_1$. Then $$a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 =0$$

What other conditions do you have?

*added based on OP's comment*

Even if $e_1$ and $e_2$ are part of a  basis, the result is not true.

Take for example
$$
e_1 = (1,0), ~e_2 = (-1, \epsilon), a_1 = a_2 = 1$$
Clearly not true for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, no matter what norm is used.

Comment: but he said it is a basis, so this is not a counterexample, but can probably come up with something like this

Comment: Saw that and updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Ah nice answer. Thanks. Really should have thought of that.